# Need help installing this software

Tags: dependencies, windows-subsystem-for-linux, curl

I'm trying to install https://github.com/ahodesuka/ahoviewer/, but apparently I need Linux and to install some dependencies. Now listen: I'm a Windows user, so I'm trying to build this on Windows.

I'm using WSL, and Ubuntu from Microsoft Store.

My first roadblock is that the dev states installing libcurl with openssl is good to avoid headaches, but I have no idea on how to do that. I already cloned the openssl repository and followed the instructions found here: https://www.openssl.org/source/gitrepo.html, but don't know how to proceed. I'm pretty sure this is really simple, but googling "build libcurl with openssl" gives me way too many different solutions on doing so, and I don't wanna screw this up

Comment: which software are you installing

Comment: this: https://github.com/ahodesuka/ahoviewer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt install curl
```

let it run and then:

```
$ curl --version
```

This shows up (mine is WSL2 on Windows 10 2004):

```
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) **libcurl/7.58.0** **OpenSSL/1.1.1** zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

**libcurl** (required to run curl) and **OpenSSL** is installed

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to clone the repo. run this `git clone https://github.com/ahodesuka/ahoviewer.git` and then `cd ahoviewer` and them `./bootstrap`. When command finishes run `make`. when it finishes building run `make install` to install it